# Show Asymptotic relationships using definitions

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am very solid at the understanding of definitions of Big-O notation along with Big-Omega and big-Theta notation. However, I struggle with actually determining through proof based reasoning using the actual definitions.

In an example that would ask:

> Show 8n<sup>3</sup> logn + 14n<sup>2</sup> = θ(n<sup>3</sup> logn).

I know that polynomials dominate logarithmic functions in terms of growth rate and that when determining asymptotic relationships one can ignore lower order terms such as the 14n<sup>2</sup>.  But how can I show this concretely using the definition of asymptotic notations as the problem asks?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove what you found informally (by ignoring the coefficient of the highest-order term and throwing away the lower order terms), that

> 8n<sup>3</sup> log(n) + 14n<sup>2</sup> = θ(n<sup>3</sup> log(n))

you have to find some positive constants c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, and n<sub>0</sub> such that

> c<sub>1</sub>n<sup>3</sup>log(n) <= 8n<sup>3</sup>log(n) + 14n<sup>2</sup> <= c<sub>2</sub>n<sup>3</sup>log(n)

for all n >= n<sub>0</sub>.

You can simplify the inequality by dividing by n<sup>3</sup>log(n) to get

> c<sub>1</sub> <= 8 + 14/nlog(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>

Now it's relatively straightforward to choose values that will make the inequalities always hold true. Start with n=2 and compute the middle portion of the inequality, then choose values for c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub>. (In this case, you want to be careful to avoid n=1, because then you'd be dividing by 0.) There are lots of values that will work. Say c<sub>1</sub>=1 and c<sub>2</sub>=15, and plug those in to the original inequality to see if it holds true for all values of n >= 2.